# Примитивы синхроинзации

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Вопрос теоретический, делал я задачу тестовую для Veeam. Знаменитая задача про архиватор многопоточный. В моей реализации отдельный поток берет порцию данных и сжимает\разжимает ее. И мне прислали ответы на мою задачу. 
Запускать новый поток для обработки каждого блока менее оптимально, чем переиспользовать существующие потоки.
Вопрос, что значит переиспользвоать существующие потоки. Когда они и так в семафоре стоят и жду когда семафор даст им возможность взять новую порцию данных.
Не используются примитивы синхроинзации для обработки изменения состояний (реализовано ожидание на sleep’ах, что менее оптимально). Вопрос, что  есть примитивы синхронизации для изменения состояний.

Comment: Посмотрите на пул потоков

Comment: пример кода с потоками и синхронизацией?

Comment: Да, просто хочу понять что есть примитивы синхронизации на примере.

Comment: ThreadingPool https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Про синхронизацию, скорее всего речь о lock-ах https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: Но вообще в задаче скорее всего лучше использовать асинхронность

Comment: @B.Vandyshev в задаче есть ограничения что именно использовать: многопоточность на тредах без пулов, .net 3,5

Comment: Так они Veeam написали что  ожидание на sleep менее оптимально, не не правильна, а менее эффективна. Хочется понять что использовать эффективно

Comment: Эффективно: не тратить время на лишнее создание/убийство потоков, не тратить время на ненужные блокировки. Например, если вам надо, чтобы какой то код обрабатывало максимум 3 потока - то создайте 3 потока и пусть они втроем колбасят код - без пересозданий потоков и семафоров.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch [monitor](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/11.5.php), например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу переиспользования потоков уже подсказали в комментах, для этого существует `ThreadPool`.

По поводу примитивов синхронизации. Windows имеет 4 примитива для синхронизации потоков:

1. Event. В .NET есть обертка в виде классов `AutoResetEvent`/`ManualResetEvent`. Нечто подобное можно сделать при помощи `Monitor.Pulse()` и `Monitor.Wait()`. Но объекты Windows более функциональные.
2. Mutex. С одноименным классом-оберткой. Подобный функционал есть и в самом .NET, в методах класса `Monitor` или в операторе `C# lock`.
3. Semaphore. С одноименным классом-оберткой.
4. Waitable timer. В NET нет обертки для этого объекта, но зато есть другие таймеры.

Кроме этого потоки можно синхронизировать по другим объектам, например потокам или процессам. Если вы в коде вызываете `thread.Join()`, вы синхронизируете один поток с окончанием работы другого.

Comment: а за что минус то?

Comment: 4? Гм, их намного больше: [Overview of synchronization primitives](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov конкретно объектов ядра виндовс всего 4. А большинство классов по вашей ссылке или обертки над ними, или .NET аналоги, которые делают тоже самое, но немного по-другому. Автор все таки спрашивал основы, и я показал самые часто используемые примитивы для синхронизации.